# System.Reactive for WPF .NET 6

Tags: system.reactive, .net-6.0

I'm trying to target .NET 6 for my WPF app, but because I'm using RX.net, the highest I can go is `net5.0-windows10.0.19041`. One example is that `ObserveOnDispatcher()` is not available when I'm targeting `net6.0-windows`, which my app makes heavy use of.

Does anybody know either A) when a .NET 6 version of RX.NET will be released, or B) any workarounds for `ObserveOnDispatcher()` or `ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current.Dispatcher)` on .NET 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively painless way I found was to simply add the `ReactiveUI.WPF` package to my WPF projects. This allowed me to advance to `net6.0-windows`, and also to use `DispatcherScheduler`. I am not using anything from ReactiveUI library, so this is technically a hack, but took 5 minutes of my time and added only a few hundred kilobytes added to the shipped binaries, so it was worth it for me to be able to move on from previously being held back on `net5.0-windows10.0.19041` because of RX.

If I had more time and skill I would dig into how the ReactiveUI.WPF source code achieved this desired effect, and apply this to my own source code... maybe someone has a more elegant, non-hack solution.

Comment: You should look into ReactiveUI, it has some *very* useful functionality, like dependent observable properties (OAPH), async commands (`ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask`) and commands that enable based on other observables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip--I just might end up using it!

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in v5.1

https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/pull/1660

You could try the nightly builds as per the readme.

https://github.com/dotnet/reactive#get-nightly-builds

Comment: Although that first link is referring to Ix.net (not RX), it's good to know that .NET 6 is in the works. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @BCA - It's RX.NET too. https://github.com/dotnet/reactive.git